# How numpy broadcasting works in this case?

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain in steps how numpy broadcasting works in this case?

```
a = np.ones((2,3))
b = np.ones((2,1,3))
c = a-b

a.shape
(2, 3)
b.shape
(2, 1, 3)
c.shape
(2, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Maybe http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/appendix/fig_broadcast_visual.html will help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-broadcasting-with-numpy-arrays/) page, it says that numpy prepends the tensor with lower rank with 1s, so in this case we have 
`a.shape = [1,2,3]`

Tile `a` along axis 1 to get `a.shape=[2,2,3]`

tile `b` along axis 2 to get `b.shape=[2,2,3]`

When the dimensions are same, subtract

Answer (score 1):

1. Prepend 1 to `a.shape`, so `a.shape -> (1,2,3)`
2. Stretch `a` along dim 1 to match `b`. so `a.shape -> (2,2,3)`
3. Stretch `b` along dim 2 to match `a`. so `b.shape -> (2,2,3)`
4. Subtract

Is that what you're looking for?